# Replace certain elements of matrix with elements of another matrix [Matlab / Octave]

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have two matrices:

```
A = [0,1,1;1,0,0;0,0,0]
B = [3,0,0;0,3,3;4,4,4]
```

And I want to replace alle the 0-elements in matrix A, with the element, that is on the same position in matrix B.

In the above example the result matrix would look like this:

```
result = [3,1,1;1,3,3;4,4,4]
```

Is there a matlab function for that purpose, or do I have to write one on my own?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easily achieved with indexing:

```
idx = A == 0;
A(idx) = B(idx);
```

Answer (score 5):

Oneliner solution using logical addressing:

```
A(A == 0) = B(A == 0);
```